# How do i list upcoming events publicly using CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: civievent, wordpress, cms-integration

I've created a couple of events and a public info pages for them in Wordpress

How do i create a page / public report that lists all these upcoming events?

Cheers
phil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you install the [CiviEvent Widget](https://aghstrategies.com/civievent-widget).

Comment: Looks like a good start - cheers